# Select can't be selected on the value

Tags: jquery, select

I generate multi select-box. Next I add some options to this select and try to set selected options. But this does not work. This is my code to set the Selected item:

```
for(xx=0;xx<obj.length; xx++)
{
    //console.log(obj.length);
    idd = obj[xx].id_produkt_lista;   
    id_statusd =  obj[xx].id_status;

    $('#sel_' + idd).find("option[value=" + id_statusd + "]").attr('selected','selected');

}
```

The variables in the code above are:

- idd - the id of the select box whose option I want to set.
- id_statusd - value which should be selected on select #*sel*+id

My html code is as follows:

```
<tbody>
    <tr id="47">
        <td id="" class="">2</td>
        <td id="">
            <select class="sel" id="sel_47">
            <option value="2" style="color: rgb(186, 175, 28);">drukowanie</option>
            <option valuea="3" style="color: rgb(8, 193, 255);">na zgrzewalni</option>
            <option value="4" style="color: rgb(112, 51, 158);">na oklejaniu</option>
            <option value="5" style="color: rgb(112, 51, 158);">laminowanie</option>
            <option value="6" style="color: rgb(112, 51, 158);">przycinanie</option>
            <option value="7" style="color: rgb(112, 51, 158);">oklejanie</option>
            <option value="8" style="color: rgb(237, 90, 21);">na cięciu</option>
            <option value="9" style="color: rgb(237, 90, 21);">na frezowaniu</option>
            <option value="10" style="color: rgb(237, 90, 21);">burtowanie i klejenie</option>
            <option value="11" style="color: rgb(237, 90, 21);">spawanie</option>
            <option value="12" style="color: rgb(237, 90, 21);">elektryka</option>
            <option value="14" style="color: rgb(90, 35, 163);">zamowienie zewnetrzne</option>
            <option value="15" style="color: rgb(62, 201, 65);">MAGAZYN-gotowe</option>
        </select>
        </td>
     </tr> 
     <tr id="48">
         <td id="" class="">3</td>
         <td id="">
        <select class="sel" id="sel_48">
            <option value="2" style="color: rgb(186, 175, 28);">drukowanie</option>
            <option value="3" style="color: rgb(8, 193, 255);">na zgrzewalni</option>
            <option value="4" style="color: rgb(112, 51, 158);">na oklejaniu</option>
            <option value="5" style="color: rgb(112, 51, 158);">laminowanie</option>
            <option value="6" style="color: rgb(112, 51, 158);">przycinanie</option>
            <option value="7" style="color: rgb(112, 51, 158);">oklejanie</option>
            <option value="8" style="color: rgb(237, 90, 21);">na cięciu</option>
            <option value="9" style="color: rgb(237, 90, 21);">na frezowaniu</option>
            <option value="10" style="color: rgb(237, 90, 21);">burtowanie i klejenie</option>
            <option value="11" style="color: rgb(237, 90, 21);">spawanie</option>
            <option value="12" style="color: rgb(237, 90, 21);">elektryka</option>
            <option value="14" style="color: rgb(90, 35, 163);">zamowienie zewnetrzne</option>
            <option value="15" style="color: rgb(62, 201, 65);">MAGAZYN-gotowe</option>
        </select>
         </td>
       </tr> 
       <tr id="49">
           <td id="" class="">4</td>
           <td id="">
            <select class="sel" id="sel_49"><option value="2" style="color: rgb(186, 175, 28);">drukowanie</option>
            <option value="3" style="color: rgb(8, 193, 255);">na zgrzewalni</option><option value="4" style="color: rgb(112, 51, 158);">na oklejaniu</option>
            <option value="5" style="color: rgb(112, 51, 158);">laminowanie</option><option value="6" style="color: rgb(112, 51, 158);">przycinanie</option>
            <option value="7" style="color: rgb(112, 51, 158);">oklejanie</option><option value="8" style="color: rgb(237, 90, 21);">na cięciu</option>
            <option value="9" style="color: rgb(237, 90, 21);">na frezowaniu</option><option value="10" style="color: rgb(237, 90, 21);">burtowanie i klejenie</option>
            <option value="11" style="color: rgb(237, 90, 21);">spawanie</option><option value="12" style="color: rgb(237, 90, 21);">elektryka</option>
            <option value="14" style="color: rgb(90, 35, 163);">zamowienie zewnetrzne</option><option value="15" style="color: rgb(62, 201, 65);">MAGAZYN-gotowe</option>
            </select></td></tr> </tbody>
```

Comment: What does 'obj[xx].id_status' output?

Comment: can you verify what is in `idd` and `id_statusd` ?

Comment: it's value witch should be selected. Like :

Comment: when I show log I see: id = 100,120, 130 and id_statusd = 3,3,12 it's means that sel_100 should have selected value 3, selc_120 should have selected value 3 and sel_130 should have selected value 12

Comment: Not the issue, second `<option>` on the first `<select>` should have the attribute `value`, not `valuea`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to set the selected attribute on the option in this way. All you have to do is use the 'val' function on the `select`.

See this in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/ht6xD/

So you code might look like:

```
for(xx=0;xx<obj.length; xx++)
{
    //console.log(obj.length);
    idd = obj[xx].id_produkt_lista;   
    id_statusd =  obj[xx].id_status;

    $('#sel_' + idd).val(id_statusd);
}
```

Unlikely to be related to the problem, but you should still fix. In the first `<select>` change

```
<option valuea="3"
```

to

```
<option value="3"
```

**EDIT**

I've mocked this up (http://jsfiddle.net/HacLZ/). Really this is something you should have considered doing yourself, but its done now.

The code works ok, in all three solutions (yours, mine and nbrooks). So there must be something else wrong. I suspect you have duplidate IDs.

Comment: Except `id_statusd` is generated within the loop; you need to map `obj` to a new array which collects the `id_status` properties, then your second method will work perfectly

Comment: soo next I have to add it in for? or not use for?

Comment: @James Nope, it turns out OP isn't actually trying to set multiple options as selected so that won't actually be helpful after all...your answer should be fine though +1

Comment: for(xx=0;xx<obj.length; xx++)
                        {
                           
                           
                            id_statusd = $.map(obj, function(elem, index) { return elem.id_status; }); 
                            
                         
                        }
                           console.log(id_statusd);
                           $(".sel_").val(id_statusd);
                       not work

Comment: The code is your comment said `$(".sel_").` If you look at my code, I'm saying: `$('#sel_' + idd)`. Can I suggest you try to learn the differences between `#id`, `element` and `.class` selectors.

Comment: now I have like this: for(xx=0;xx<obj.length; xx++)
                        {
                             idE = $.map(obj, function(elem, index) { return elem.id_produkt_lista; });   
                            id_statusd = $.map(obj, function(elem, index) { return elem.id_status; }); 
                            
                         
                        
                        }
                         
                         $("#sel_"+idE).val(id_statusd);

Comment: this code : $('#sel_100').val(4) not working too... (when I have sel_100 ofc) it's my all code : http://wklej.org/id/832372/

Comment: I've mocked this up. See EDIT above.

Answer (score 1):

[`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) accepts a callback parameter which can compute the new value of the element, given the index and the previous value.

Something like this should work:

```
$("select.sel").val(function(index, value) {
    return obj[index]["id_status"];
});
```

Comment: Very nice solution, although your wouldn't need to reference `id_status` with its dictionary accessor `["id_status"]` - `return obj[index].id_status`.

Answer (score 0):

If idd and id_statusd contains expected values it should work ok, however try changing your selecting line to:

```
$('#sel_' + idd + ' option[value="' + id_statusd + '"]').attr('selected','selected');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

***JS CODE***

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select').change(function(){
         var id = $(this).attr('id');
        console.log($('#'+id+'').find('option:selected').text());
    });     
});
```

***[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vabqv/67/)***

Comment: @user1678400 if modification needed or my solution is not asymptotic to your thought please notify.